# Is the camera in the new iPad using "4S optics"?

Tags: hardware, camera, ipad

[Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) merely identifies it as a "5 megapixel iSight" camera. [MacRumors claims](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/16/new-ipad-using-same-camera-sensors-found-in-older-products/) that Apple is reusing older parts. I recall reading that the new iPad has a better camera than prior models, so I'm confused. Which one is it? Advanced optics or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the iPhone 4S has an 8mp camera.

The prior iPhone 4 had a 5mp camera though.

But, yes, the older iPad had a much worse camera - less than 1mp.

This would seem to show it's from the iPhone 4: [The new iPad camera: we've seen it somewhere before](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/03/16/ipad-cameras-seen-before/)

Megapixels aren't everything - but the new iPad certainly has the best camera in an iPad so far. The front facing camera isn't that great though, even with the rear one hugely improved.

Comment: It has been [confirmed](http://www.chipworks.com/en/technical-competitive-analysis/resources/recent-teardowns/2012/03/the-new-ipad-a-closer-look-inside/) that the rear camera of the iPad 3rd is in fact the same as used in the iPhone 4: "Omnivision OV5650, 1.75 um pixel pitch, 5 MP back illuminated CMOS Image Sensor"